# Issues sending email using my php form

Tags: php, html, vb.net

I am trying to set up a simple "Contact Me" form for my website using VB.NET 2015. But I am not able to receive any emails. Here are my files:

PHP:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");

//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"], ENT_QUOTES);
$subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST["subject"], ENT_QUOTES);
$comment = htmlspecialchars($_POST["comment"], ENT_QUOTES);

$comment = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $comment);//message can't have \n.

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $email . "\r\n";

if(mail("foo@test.com ", $subject, $comment, $headers)){
    //no error
    exit;
}

echo "Error sending mail";

?>
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```
module OnlinePortfolio {
    export class ContactMe {

        public static Email() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "SendMail.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "subject": $("#subject").text(), "email": $("#email").text(), "message": $("#comment").text()
                },
                success: function (data, status) {
                    if (data === "") {
                        alert("Message sent successfully");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("There was an issue with sending your message");
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorDescription) {
                    console.error('Something happened while sending the request: ' + status + ' - ' + errorDescription);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <form>
        Email: <input id="email" type="text" /><br />
        Subject: <input id="subject" type="text" /><br />
        Message:<br />
        <textarea id="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="OnlinePortfolio.ContactMe.Email()">
    </form>
<html>
```

The email provided above is just for this post. I am fairly new to php but based on some research I did this should be working. I get no errors when I click the submit button. I also opened the debug console and get no errors as well. Can someone please help me understand why I am not receiving emails?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are trying it on localhost it will not send email....

Comment: @VaibhavMalve Thank you for the prompt reply. So how do I get it to send email?

Comment: You should have to put it on a live server, then only the SMTP or simply the mail thing will work

Comment: For local you can use phpmailer library...its easy ...there you can use your gmail credenitails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use PHPMailer(https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)) from local

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using PHP in-built mail function. Unfortunately, It will not work on localhost.
You need to run that from a remote server to make it work.
In case, if you want to run that from localhost, use a third party library say phpmailer.

Answer (score 0):

1:localhost can`t use mail() for send e-mail , first upload to server . if you must use in localhost use phpmailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2:your  not set action ! in real html script set it